# Having trouble aligning photo and text horizontally

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to place a member's photos next to their comments.  I am working from a wireframe that requires side by side image and text.

On the default tab there are 3 comments.  I am trying to also display the members photo on the left of the comment, but can't get it to render for some reason.

Any idea why the photo isn't rendering on the left and how I can align it? I am looking in Firebug, but somehow can't find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your problem

```
<div style="float:left><img src=/img/member_photo/1/mid_thumb.jpeg width="100" ></div>
```

it should be:

```
<div style="float:left"><img src="/img/member_photo/1/mid_thumb.jpeg" width="100" ></div>
```

You missed the quotes

Comment: thanks that fixed it, but now somehow the text area overlaps with the comment texts :) Any idea what is still going wrong there? :)

Comment: here is what i recommend, [Validate your html](http://validator.w3.org/) it will help you see everything wrong with the syntax

Comment: fixed it!  Will accept your answer in 4 min when this site lets me.

Comment: There is a link in my previous comment : http://validator.w3.org/ . you can go to the Direct input section to manually insert your code in

Answer (score 0):

bad html

https://i.stack.imgur.com/orinI.jpg
[image]

### edit

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSLnw.jpg

[image]

Comment: thanks - actually even fixing the quotes there somehow broke the text area - would you know what is still not right there? Thanks!